# NIO sockets - distributed system

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, nio

I have three processes called LWA1, LWA2 and LWA3. Each has a server, with the port being 55555 for LWA1, 55556 for LWA2 and 55557 for LWA3.
Also, each process has a client in order to connect to the other processes.

Each process should be able to write and read to the other processes. So:

- LWA1 should write and read to/from LWA2 and LWA3
- LWA2 should write and read to/from LWA1 and LWA3
- LWA3 should write and read to/from LWA1 and LWA2

At the moment, each process performs two writes, but only receives one message. The ouput for each process is as follows (the tabbed prints belong to the client, the untabbed ones to the server).

LWA1:

```
Setting up server with port: 55555
Server configured.

    Opening sockets to port 55556 and port 55557
    Sending lamport request: LamportRequest{clock=0, process='LWA1', id=1}
Key accepted
Reading data from server
I read: LamportRequest{clock=0, process='LWA3', id=3}
Key accepted
```

LWA2:

```
Setting up server with port: 55556
Server configured.

    Opening sockets to port 55557 and port 55555
Key accepted
Reading data from server
I read: LamportRequest{clock=0, process='LWA1', id=1}
Key accepted
    Sending lamport request: LamportRequest{clock=0, process='LWA2', id=2}
```

LWA3:

```
Setting up server with port: 55557
Server configured.

    Opening sockets to port 55555 and port 55556
Key accepted
Key accepted
    Sending lamport request: LamportRequest{clock=0, process='LWA3', id=3}
Reading data from server
I read: LamportRequest{clock=0, process='LWA2', id=2}
```

**As you can see, each client writes to the other two a LamportRequest, but the other two only receive one message. Why is the other message not getting trough?**

I suspect it might be something related to the keys in the server but no idea what could be. Also, I don't fully understand them. Correct me if I'm wrong:

Each connection to a Selector is represented with a different (SelectableChannel) key, therefore the Iterator in the server LWA1 (for example) should only have (and thus, only listen to events) two keys, one for LWA2 and another one for LWA3, right? I tried attaching and integer to each key in the keyAccept method to distinguish them, which worked fine, but when printing the attached integer in the keyRead method, it showed null. Is the key in that method a new one? A third key just appeared out of nowhere?

Bonus question: I'm supposed to implement this structure in a single thread. Currently I use two, one for server and one for client. Once it's working, any tips into how to unify them?

------------------ CODE -----------------

The server (simplified for reading purposes) goes as follows:

```
public TalkToBrotherSocket(int clock, int port) {
    this.port = port;
    this.clock = clock;

    try {
        setServer();
        System.out.println("Server configured.\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Wait for an event one of the registered channels
            selector.select();

            // Iterate over the set of keys for which events are available
            Iterator selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) selectedKeys.next();
                selectedKeys.remove();

                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Check if they key is ready to accept a new socket connection
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    keyAccept(key);
                    System.out.println("Key accepted");
                } else if (key.isReadable()){
                    System.out.println("Reading data from server");
                    keyRead(key);
                } else if (key.isWritable()){
                    System.out.println("Writting data from server");
                    keyWrite(key); //unused at the moment
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


private void keyRead(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    // Create a SocketChannel to read the request
    SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

    // Clear out our read buffer so it's ready for new data
    buffer.clear();

    // Attempt to read off the channel
    int numRead;
    try {
        numRead = socketChannel.read(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Closing socket");
        // The remote forcibly closed the connection, cancel
        // the selection key and close the channel.
        key.cancel();
        socketChannel.close();
        return;
    }

    if (numRead == -1) {
        System.out.println("Shutting down socket");
        // Remote entity shut the socket down cleanly. Do the
        // same from our end and cancel the channel.
        key.channel().close();
        key.cancel();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("I read: " + new String(buffer.array()).trim());
}

private void keyAccept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    // For an accept to be pending the channel must be a server socket channel.
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();

    // Accept the connection and make it non-blocking
    SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
    //Socket socket = socketChannel.socket();
    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

    // Register the new SocketChannel with our Selector, indicating
    // we'd like to be notified when there's data waiting to be read
    socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}

private void setServer() throws IOException {
    // Create a new selector
    selector = Selector.open();

    // Create a new non-blocking server socket channel
    serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

    // Bind the server socket to the specified address and port
    serverChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port));

    // Register the server socket channel, indicating an interest in
    // accepting new connections
    serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
}
```

The client (simplified for reading purposes) goes as follows:

```
public NIOClient(int clock, int firstPort, int secondPort, int id, String process) {
    this.process = process;
    this.clock = clock;
    this.id = id;

    try {
        System.out.println("\tOpening sockets to port " + firstPort + " and port " + secondPort);
        firstClient = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", firstPort));
        secondClient = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", secondPort));
        firstBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        secondBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        sendRequests();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendRequests() {
    LamportRequest lamportRequest = new LamportRequest(clock, process, id);
    firstBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(lamportRequest.toString().getBytes());
    secondBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(lamportRequest.toString().getBytes());
    String converted = new String(firstBuffer.array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("\tSending lamport request: " + converted);
    try {
        firstClient.write(firstBuffer);
        secondClient.write(secondBuffer);
        firstBuffer.clear();
}
```

Initialized as follows:

```
System.out.println("Setting up server with port: " + myPort);
TalkToBrotherSocket talkToBrotherSocket = new TalkToBrotherSocket(clock, myPort);
talkToBrotherSocket.start();

new NIOClient(clock, firstPort, secondPort, id, process);
```

Comment: `firstClient.write(buffer)` empties the buffer if it succeeds. You need to save the buffer position and limit before the write and restore them for the second write. Or just create two buffers from the message.

Comment: @user207421 thanks for the comment. I printed the buffer after the first write and it still had the message in it, but just to make sure, I made a second buffer and used it on the second write. Didn't fix the problem, but I'll keep the changes you suggested just to be safe. In any case, thank you for your contribution.

Comment: It doesn't mater what got printed. What matters is what got sent, and your original code sent nothing the second time. No two ways about that.  Provide your current code and let's see.

Comment: @user207421 Edited the post with the changes and its new output. Changes have been done only to the sendRequests method.

Comment: Sigh. Read what I wrote. 'Create two buffers from the message'. Assigning a reference doesn't constitute creating two buffers at all, let alone 'from the message'. You need to call the `wrap()` method again and assign the result to the second buffer variable.

Comment: @user207421 My bad, did it right this time around. Sorry for not paying attention. Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Following @user207421's comments, I added a new second buffer. Changes to the sendRequests method have been edited into the original post.